# Brightcove CMS API Search Sort parameter not working

Tags: javascript, api, brightcove

When querying brightcove the result set is not sorted by the field specified in the sort parameter

If I place the sort parameter as the first parameter the results are sorted but the Q parameter seems to be ignored because the results do not match what was requested. 
The ouput of the query from the console window:

```
/videos?q=tags:wood,boat+-name:%22Repairing%20Wood%20Boats%22&limit=7&offset=0&sort=-created_at
```

My query from as it exists in javascript:

```
var endPoint = encodeURI('?q=tags:' + tagQuery + '+-name:"' + videoName + '"&limit=7&sort=-created_at');
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete URL that is being sent to Brightcove?